# My server boots a kernel I don't recognize

Tags: virtualization, openvz, dedicated-server, linux-kernel

On my dedicated server I'm running Debian 7.5 as an OS. I have installed OpenVZ for amd64 architecture to use the benefits of virtualization but after successfully installing it (following [these directions](http://openvz.org/Installation_on_Debian)) the OpenVZ kernel is not booting. When I run `uname -r` it shows `3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64` and not an OpenVZ kernel.

Even after modifying `/etc/default/grub` and setting `default` to a number other than `0` 
and running `update-grub`, on reboot it's like nothing happened and it always boots the same default kernel instead of the OpenVZ kernel.

I don't know if my hosting provider is using a customized kernel version because I have never seen this particular kernel?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Not everyone is a native English speaker. It's better to _edit_ such posts.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I do that quite a bit.  But don't all languages have sentences?  Sloppy writing = sloppy thought.

Comment: sorry for my bad english i havn't checked the sentences and i should be    more careful next time ,thanks for modifying my question to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a dedicated server with OVH. By default these boot an OVH-provided kernel from the network, not the kernel installed on your server. You need to change the configuration of your server, in your OVH account management web pages, to [boot from the hard drive](http://help.ovh.com/KernelInstall).

Comment: Thank you Michael you saved my life,  the ovh guide was so helpful, thanks again for solving my newbie problem ^^